# Overusing CInt?

Tags: vbscript

I am fixing a defect in some classic ASP using VBScript and I've come across the following line:

```
variable1 = CInt((CInt(variable2) MOD CInt(3600))\ CInt(60))
```

Is it necessary to call `CInt(3600)` and `CInt(60)` when we are using them in an expression? Would this be an equivalent expression?

```
variable1 = (CInt(variable2) MOD 3600) \ 60
```

Comment: Hey, that looks like code I've had to support...  It's always good for a chuckle.

Comment: note that `CInt` is for 16 bit signed integers. Maybe it'd be better to use `CLng` to avoid possible overflows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer literals are already integer type, as are arithmetic operations on integers.  The two expressions are equivalent.